# Android: where to store data? Data base or xml?

Tags: java, android

For example a have set of words. 1000 words. 
And on click i need to take one of these words and show to the user.
User can't add words.

Where is better to keep this set of words?
First of all i had idea to store them in DB, but then i thought that is better to store them in xml file, and on application start get them all in List and use.

Is it good way? Or it's better to use DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If user can not add/delete/update the words then it's better to use the XML file instead of the database. you can store the words in XML. but if your 1000 words are dynamic and coming from the HTTP call then you have to create the database for the same and if not then static data is enough.

Comment: is it faster to retrieve from the xml than database ?

Comment: Really?  I would have said database for mutable word lists, either one for immutable, database if you add to the list on the fly even if users can't.